# flutter) I want to use a listview to jump directly to a specific section

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

As shown in the picture, I want to go directly to the corresponding list view when I press the button.

Instead of scrolling through the list, you can use the buttons to move left and right.

This is my current code.

As shown below, I am running a pageview called body (which changes briefly after using listview), and I know how to come out in order, but I don't know what to use to get it out of a specific number. Do you have a yes or another question?

```
          GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Choice821()),);
            },
```

2

```
class Choice821 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    QuestionController _controller = Get.put(QuestionController());
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('복습 시험', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight:FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 20,),),
        centerTitle: true,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

2

```
child: PageView.builder(
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
  controller: _questionController.pageController,
  onPageChanged: _questionController.updateTheQnNum,
  itemCount: _questionController.questions.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) => ayotube(
    question: _questionController.questions[index],
    id: _questionController.questionNumber.value,
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do this:

// jump to page index with animation

```
_questionController.pageController.animateToPage(index);
```

// or jump to page index without animation

```
_questionController.pageController.jumpToPage(index);
```

Comment: How can I make my code work while running the class at the same time?
Should I put it inside ayotube()?

Comment: I should be able to use it with Navigator!

Comment: @eno2 i really dont know what you mean , if you mean where you could put those actions , you can simply call them on button click or a function

Comment: Yes. I put it on the button. But I wonder if it runs from the parent file. I was wondering if it is possible to use the code above with the navigator or function call in the parent file to navigate to the index number page of the child file.